# why nodejs buffer is increasing memory usage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

I have a code that records camera input from client into server as such :

```
  async function saveIntoMp4(chunks) {

      const options = { type: "video/webm" }
      let blob = new Blob(chunks, options);
      chunks.length = 0 // to stop any memory leaks
        const buffer = Buffer.from(await blob.arrayBuffer());

        try {
        fs.writeFile(
        `./videos/1.mp4`,
        buffer,
        () =>  console.log("video is saved!" )
      );
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('ERROR', error)
        }
      
  }
```

Every time this piece of code is called I get the exact amount of the video saved ( or roughly the same amount ) occupying my ram. I have absolutely no idea how to deal with this despite. How can I overcome this ( possible memory leak ) problem from my code?

Comment: Does the garbage collector never run?

Comment: @Konrad I have --expose-gc on my nodejs and I can see the flag is enabled with pm2. I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

My guess you shouldn't create a buffer from the chunks (this blows the memory twice), but write the chunks directly. This is pseudo code, tweak it to a working version:

```js
import { open } from 'node:fs/promises';
 
async function saveIntoMp4(chunks) {

  const file = await open('./videos/1.mp4', 'w');

  for(const chunk of chunks){
    await file.write(chunk);
  }

  return file.close();
     
}
```

Comment: Probably want some error handling so you close the file if there's a write error.